# Password - String comparison

Tags: java, android, arrays

My app consists of an `Activity`, which asks for a `String` password, in order to launch a second `Activity`. I am using an `EditText` for input and a `Button` for verification. If the `Button` is pressed, the app should check whether the inserted password, (let's assume it's "ABC") matches the password in the array.  If not, set the inserted password to a red color.

```
 public class Login extends AppCompatActivity{

    Button   mButton;
    EditText mEdit;
    String [] mArray;


  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.anmelden_button);
        mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        Log.v("EditText", mEdit.getText().toString());
                    }
                });

        String [] mArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.password);

        if (mArray.equals(mEdit.getText().toString())){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondactivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }else{
            mEdit.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
}
```

**My problem is**, that when I insert "ABC" and press the Button, nothing happens at all.

Comment: Nothing? Not even a logging statement?

Comment: Just "V/EditText: ABC" but I've got no Idea what this should tell me.

Comment: Bc the bold stuff shall show the actual problem, non-bolt as a nearer description, but I can remove this if you want so :)

Comment: @Quacksilber well, that's all you've got in your `onClick` method - what else do you expect to happen when you click the button?

Comment: `Log.v("EditText", mEdit.getText().toString());` That is the only line of code in the onClick so it seems it worked perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through all the passwords first, then check to see if you found what you wanted.

Your onclick listener should something look like this:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        String [] mArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.password);

        // loop to check all passwords
        for (String s : mArray) {
            if (s.equals(mEdit.getText().toString())) {
                // found the password
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondactivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
        }

        mEdit.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    }
});
```

Comment: @Quacksilber the text doesn't turn red AND the new activity doesn't come up? Can't help you there then, something else is wrong in your code.

Comment: Ok, I changed sth in the strings.xml and it works now, thank a lot for your help!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your password checking code inside the onClickListener

Loop through each element of the array, checking it against the value in your EditText

Comment: Your check method is incorrect. You're checking an array object against a String.

Comment: Allright, I followed all your instructions, and also changed all array stuff into a string, but now I get an error, telling me, this line (String [] mArray = getResources().getString(R.string.password);) doesn't work, bc it requires String[] and found String. Whats the diffference there?

Comment: That line says "_assign this String to this array_" - you can't mix types like that. Imagine you wrote this `int i = "This is a String"`. That won't work for the same reason - it says "_assign this String to this int_".